# Implement save() Action for Object with Relationship?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following Grails GORM domain classes:

```
class Category {
 hasMany = [items: Item]
}

class Item {
  belongsTo = [category: Category]
}
```

In my ItemController I have a create() and save() action for an item.

The save() action looks like this:

```
  @Transactional
  def save(Item item) { 

   ...

   if (item.hasErrors()) {
   ...
   }

   category.addToItems(item)
   if (!category.save(flush: true)) { ... }

  }
```

The problem is that `item.hasErrors()` will report an error because `item.category`` is null. It is not linked to the category yet.

If I switch blocks like:

```
   category.addToItems(item)
   if (!category.save(flush: true)) { ... }

   if (item.hasErrors()) {
   ...
   }
```

then I cannot check for item errors before I save.

**What is the best way to handle this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
category.addToItems(item)
if (item.hasErrors()) {
 ...
}
if (!category.save(flush: true)) { ... }
```

?

EDIT:

In my grails projects I manually handle collections. That means in this example that I add to the Category:

```
static mapping = {
    items cascade: 'none'
}
```

And then in the saving of objects I first save the category then the belonging items. Like:

```
category.addToItems(items)
if (!category.save(flush:true)) { ... } // will not save items
if (!item.save(flush:true)) { ... }
```

If you do not want to save the category in case of the error in items, make sure you are in a transaction and use

```
item.save(failOnError:true)
```

Comment: It still reports the error because the relationship is not saved yet.

Answer (score 0):

`category.addToItems(item)
   if (!category.save(flush: true)) { ... }`

Don't handle this in Item controller. Create Item first (without relation) then create category. use

`Category.addToItems(item).save(failOnError:true)`

Why don't you leave it to scaffolding to generate code for you at this stage? It manages relationship and you can clear your mind about what is happening and later on tailor for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `obj.validate( [ 'someProp', 'someOtherProp' ] )` to validate only the properties you want.

See [ref-doc](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) for details